# Is const T& rf = lvalue of T an identity conversion?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

```
T t;
const T& rf = t; // #1
```

Consider the initialization `#1` shown above.  Is it an identity conversion?  In other words, does `rf` bind directly to the initializer expression?  If not that, how many standard conversions does #1 have and what are these conversion named?

Comment: Where is `#2` ?

Comment: @Ayxan  no #2,i just want to understand something about #1

Comment: @mfnx  there are no overload resolution here...

Comment: The concept of "identity conversion" is used only in overload resolution.

Comment: @L.F. could you  interpret the `identity conversion`,The standard is not clear about this concept

Comment: This is a pitfall for budding language lawyers ... it looks like it might be a qualification conversion, if you don't read the text properly

Comment: @M.M how to explain it? Is "qualification conversion" only work in pointer type?

Answer (score 2):

It is an identity conversion.  [[over.ics.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.ref#1):

> **When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity
>   conversion,** unless the argument expression has a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit
>   conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion ([over.best.ics]).
>   [...] If the parameter binds directly to the result of applying a
>   conversion function to the argument expression, the implicit
>   conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence, with the
>   second standard conversion sequence either an identity conversion or,
>   if the conversion function returns an entity of a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type, a derived-to-base Conversion.

(emphasis mine)

In your case, the argument type is the same as the parameter type, so the argument type neither derives from the parameter type nor requires a user-defined conversion function.

Comment: I am confused about this,why the conversion is not a qualifaction conversion,for example `int a =0; const  int& ptr = &a`,we know it is a qualifaction conversion,But why const T& rf = t; is not

Comment: @jackX Qualification conversion has nothing to do with this, actually. It's about pointers (`int*` -> `const int*`) and noexcept functions (`void (*)() noexcept` -> `void (*)()`)